# Word limit on Case Details

Tags: civicase

After updating to CiviCRM 5.27.0 on Drupal, a user reports that pasting large text content in the "Details" box in CiviCase activities cutoff the text. Is anyone else seeing this issue?

Comment: Not sure if this is possible but after doing troubleshooting, it appears that the emoji's in emails cut off the text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The emoji part sounds familiar. If the db tables are not utf8mb4 then emojis get cut off (or fatal error depending on mysql/mariadb/version).

You can convert your db tables to utf8mb4.

In addition you may also want to apply this patch https://patch-diff.githubusercontent.com/raw/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/17716.patch

Comment: The patch fixed the issue! Thank you!